# How do I get two arrows in between my carousel indicators?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

Example of what I want my indicator to look like

[image]

My code

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">

                <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
              </ol>
```

Comment: You can try adding buttons.

Comment: one question. I can't add anything that's not li inside ol so what would be the best way to add the arrow in between the ol?

Comment: You can add buttons by using Javascript

Comment: How do I do that?